# Posicionamento de imagens GridLayout Android

Tags: android, android-layout

UPDATE

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação mobile, utilizando o gridLayout e gostaria de deixar uma imagem do lado da outra, no caso a imageView1 no lado da imageView 2 ,  embaixo imageViem3 a lado da imageView4 mas agora as image  imageView2, imageView3, imageView4 saem do espaço delimitado para tela do celular

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.tulio.exercicio5.MainActivity">


<GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="3"
    android:orientation="horizontal">



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/aliados"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/chamado3"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginRight="290dp"

        />



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/regresso"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="1"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:layout_row="1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/john_wick" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/residentevil6"
        android:layout_below ="@+id/imageView4"/>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/xxxreativado"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView6"/>

</GridLayout>
```

Comment: Isso ai não é legal não. Procure sobre RecyclerView

Comment: mas essa não seria a melhor forma de fazer o que eu estou fazendo utlizando o GridLayout ?

Comment: GridLayout só será valido nessa situação se nunca houver mudança nos filmes. Caso você queria alterar, e inserir um novo filme, terá que alterar o layout novamente. O interessante é você criar uma lista de filmes usando RecyclerView, assim você deixara isso mais dinâmico.

Comment: Por exemplo, veja essa imagem usando RecyclerView + CardView: https://www.androidhive.info/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/android-integrating-cardview-and-recyclerview-music-app.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `width` seu terceiro ImageView está `match_parent` , por isso ocupa toda largura do scrollView

UPDATE:
Ajustei as dimensões, linhas e colunas.
Algo como:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/aliados"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_row="0"
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/chamado3"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_row="0"
    />



<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/regresso"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:layout_column="0"
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_row="1"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/john_wick" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView6"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/residentevil6"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_row="2"/>


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView7"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/xxxreativado"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_row="2"/>
```

Comment: eu mudei e a imageView4 não ficou do lado da imageView3

Comment: ao invés de android:layout_columnSpan nos imageViews, utilize android:layout_column. O columnSpan seria para unir colunas numa linha.

Comment: eu atualizei a pergunta André Ozawa agora que coloquei como android:layout_column as imageView2,imageView3,imageView4 saem do espaço limitado para tela do celualr, coloquei a imagem para ilustrar e atualizei meu código para vocês verem

Comment: Tente todas as larguras e comprimentos dos ImageViews como wrap_content. A o segundo ImageView tem a propriedade layout_gravity=fill_horizontal, o que faz com que preencha o comprimento.

Comment: obrigado André Ozawa era isso mesmo que eu tinha que fazer